# Dockerfile CMD script runs differently to running script manually in container

Tags: python, docker

I have a dockerfile with the following end

```
CMD python app/start.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And when I try calling `run` (through compose) it gives me an error from my python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/start.py", line 4, in <module>
    from utils.foo import bar
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

However, when I call `run ... bash` (again through compose) or set the compose command argument to `bash`, and then in the bash terminal that comes up run:

```
python app/start.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The script runs perfectly.

I assume this is something to do with how folder structure is handled on startup. Is there something I don't understand about how `CMD` works in dockerfiles?

**Updates**

- Running with `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` makes no difference
- Setting `CMD` to `bash -c "python app/start.py arg1 arg2 arg3"` makes no difference

Comment: Add the location of `start.py` in `sys.path` using `import os, inspect; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())),'app'))))`.

Comment: Or even simpler `import sys, os; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'app'))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best solution, but it ended up working for me.

I simply created a new top level file `start.py` with:

```
from app.start import startup

startup()
```

And replaced the command:

```
CMD python start.py arg1, arg2, arg3
```

And it worked fine. I feel this somewhat confirms my suspicion that it was something to do with the file hierarchy, but as to why this occurs only when running off `CMD` still has me stumped. Any suggestions for a better solution would be much appreciated.